# How to auto layout a view from another xib/nib as subview inside split view programatically?

Tags: objective-c, resize, autolayout, nsview

In my OS X project I've written a custom view controller for a NSView which is defined in a separate xib file. The view contains buttons and subviews which are defined using auto layout, too.

Now I tried to load the view programatically and tried to attach the loaded view as subview to the split view.

I created a small helper for setting the constraints

```
-(void)autoresizeConstraintsForSubview:(NSView*)subview inSuperview:(NSView*)superview {

[superview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subview
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:superview
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                     multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];

[superview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subview
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:superview
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                     multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];

[superview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subview
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:superview
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                     multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];

[superview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subview
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:superview
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                     multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];
}

- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    [super windowDidLoad];

    // Implement this method to handle any initialization after your window controller's window has been loaded from its nib file.
    // now load the detailed views.
    self.chart1 = [[BTChartViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChartView" bundle:nil];
    [self.chart1.view setFrameOrigin:NSMakePoint(0, 0)];
    [self.view1 addSubview:self.chart1.view];
    [self.chart1.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    [self autoresizeConstraintsForSubview:self.chart1.view inSuperview:self.view1];

    //[self.window  visualizeConstraints:[self.chart1.view constraints]];
    //[self.window  visualizeConstraints:[self.view1 constraints]];
}
```

Where self.view1, self.view2 is an outlet to the custom views in the split view. self.view2 is not used at this moment.
And self.chart1 is a working view controller which loads the view (some charts).

The constraints seem to work at the first glance, because the view is loaded, all content is displayed and the chart is displayed perfectly. But after setting the chart view as subview the split view is not able to resize anymore. The left area of the split view is fixed and I am not able to move the split bar anymore.

If I am setting everything up inside interface builder it works perfectly. My goal is to setup a couple of split views so that I have 4 areas with independent view controllers.

How can I setup the constraints to not block the resizing behavior?
The displayed size of the subview is alway the "intrinsic size" in interface builder. But I want the subview to always have the size of the custom view of the split view and be able to resize the split view.

Does someone know what's going wrong here?